# silverlight validation on textbox inside usercontrol

Tags: silverlight, validation

As the title states, I have a usercontrol with a textbox inside. The purpose of the user control is to add a spell check button and character count below the textbox. But for the most part, I'm using it just like a normal textbox:

```
  <controls:SuperTextBox Text="{Binding Accomplishments, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                                          Height="200" EnableCharacterCounting="True" EnableSpellChecking="True" AcceptsReturn="True"
                                          TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

The problem I'm having is that I no longer get the nice red border when validation fails for the field. What do I need to do to reenable that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here, it's to relay the validation of your UserControl back to the textbox.

I did answer a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168438/show-validation-error-in-usercontrol/5896917#5896917).