# How to make Top Level user control Validation.HasErrors match the child TextBox.Validation.HasErrors?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a **UserControl** with a **TextBox** inside. I want to show a message at the **UserControl level** when there is an **error at the TextBox Level**. And show too an error message at TexBox level.

We are not using MVVM. This is a reusable control.
However, this is a reusable control, and the people using it, will be likely using MVVM themselves.

They would add it to their View like this:

```
<myUserControlNamespace:MyUserControl x:Name="control1" Value="{Binding Value}" OtherProperty="{Binding OtherValue}" />
```

My Control inside has a TexBox, which is binded to "Value". Value it is a Double, so when the user inputs a letter on the TexBox an error is thrown. My TextBox is binded similar to this:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="valueTextBox" Style="{DynamicResource ValidatingTextBox}"                 
            Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=valueTextBox}" 
            Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor="{Binding}" >
<TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}"Mode="TwoWay" >
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type unitConversion:UnitConversionControl}}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" />
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type unitConversion:UnitConversionControl}}" Path="OtherProperty"/>                    
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

The Style ValidatingTexBox has something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ValidatingTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding ErrorContent}"  Height="16" Margin="2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="LightPink" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,28"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I would like the users of my client to use my control in a similar way that I use the TextBox. Setting MyUserControl style, and using the Validation.ErrorTemplate to show the errors.

When there is an error in the TexBox I would like my Control to have an error too, so the people using my control could handle it, for example by using an Validation.ErrorTemplate.

Is there a way to "**cascade up**" the errors?

I read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168438/show-validation-error-in-usercontrol), he is using **INotifyDataErrorInfo**, I can't because I am using .Net 4.0, but I read that I could instead use IDataErrorInfo. I would have to make my control implement IDataErrorInfo. Is this correct?

Let me know if I need to add some more detail.

Comment: It depends on the design on how you want it to bubble up to the UserControl. If there are any errors in its children, do you want to show like an error message + the validation error that it produces in the actual control(textbox)?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis yes that is exactly what I want. To be able to show an error message at the level of the UserControl as well as its children.

Comment: You can probably create a custom user control that shows the errors and since the ValidationError returns a collection of errors, you can populate it with its result.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis I am not sure I understand. I want to show the errors when they happen, so how would I get notified of this, so then I could show it in my custom control? Sorry if this is a lame question

Comment: When you validate it should return an object ValidationResult and it should have the ErrorMessage property, from that you can pass it to your custom control to show the ErrorMessage too. You don't have to worry about the child controls because WPF is doing the error for you.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis, I am not sure I have explained myself properly. My control is going to be used by others. They will have a ViewModel and a View, and inside that View they will be using my control. My Control has a texbox, and i want it to show the error messages. But the users Of my control want to be able to handle the erros inside it, like when you use a textbox. What I want to accomplish, is that when the texbox has errors, the error should be bubbled up to the UserControl.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39022/discussion-between-leo-lorenzo-luis-and-dzyann)